# Optimize concave function divided by a linear function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, monotone-functions

If I divide a monoton concave upper and lower bounded function by a linear function, whould the result be concave? Or even easy to optimize?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Upper/lower bound of what?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the result would not necessarily be concave.  For instance, $x^{1/2}$ is concave, but $x^{1/2}/x$ is convex.

However, if the numerator is a concave quadratic and the denominator is a nonnegative linear (affine) function over its domain, the result is an easy to maximize concave function. If the numerator is a concave quadratic and the denominator is a nonpositive  linear (affine) function over its domain, the result is an easy to minimize convex function.  See the last paragraph of Example 3.4 on p. 76 of ["Convex Optimization" by Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/).  If using CVX, the function `quad_over_lin` can be used to implement such cases.

Boundedness of the numerator is irrelevant to whether the quotient is concave.